# How can I refresh tableView and JSON datas with button or pull to refresh ?

Tags: json, swift, refresh, reload

I'm new at swift and i can not find how to how to refresh TableView and JSON datas same time. First refresh Json after refresh TableView. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add pull to refresh class to your `UITableView`

```
private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
var tableView: UITableView!
```

Then in `ViewDidLoad` add it as a subview to your `tableView` and you can even change its color and text.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    } else {
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Fetching Data ...", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor(red:0/255, green:168/255, blue:225/255, alpha:1.0)])
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

}
```

Add a target to it with a selector function when value changes as shown above.

```
@objc private func refreshData(_ sender: Any) {

   //load the data from the server and 
   //parse and put it in an array then reload your table view

}
```